# exc_bad_access from ASIHTTPRequest when popping view controller while downloading for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, download, asihttprequest, exc-bad-access

I have a custom navigation controller so i made my own back button that does

```
-(void)navigateBack{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

and on the view did load, I request for many images using the ASINetworkQueue

```
-(void)sendRequest:(NSURL *)url withParams:(NSDictionary *)params andSelector:(NSString *)selector{
NSString *jsonString = [params yajl_JSONString];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:jsonString forKey:@"json"];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:15];
[[self networkQueue] setDelegate:self];
[[self networkQueue] setRequestDidFinishSelector:NSSelectorFromString(selector)];
[[self networkQueue] setRequestDidFailSelector:@selector(asiRequestFailed:)];
[[self networkQueue] addOperation:request];
[[self networkQueue] go];
}
```

Essentially, anytime I send an HTTP request, i just do [self sendRequest:].
When I go to this viewcontroller, then press back before all the images are downloading, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS that points to the line where ASIHTTPFormRequest tries to perform the selector.  I tried putting

```
[networkQueue cancelAllOperations];[self setNetworkQueue:nil];
```

in my dealloc method, and i put breakpoints before and after this, and I can see from the GDB that there are no more requests in the queue, but the error keeps showing.  Am i missing something?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your delegates will likely get called to notify you of the cancellation. You need to remove all the delegates in your dealloc method, eg:

```
for (ASIHTTPRequest *req in [queue operations])
{
    [req setDelegate:nil];
    [req cancel];
}
[queue setDelegate:nil];
```

(and also progress delegates etc if you're using them)

Comment: awesome! this was what i was looking for.  I didn't know how to look through the requests in the queue.  I checked in the documentations for ASIHTTPRequests but i didn't see anything like that forloop.  how did you know that `[queue operations]` was an array of the requests? By the way, i had to change the statement inside the forloop to `[req clearDelegatesAndCancel]` for it to work

Comment: Excellent. ASINetworkQueue is a subclass of NSOperationQueue (see the top of the .h) - it's the latter that has the operations method (see Apple docs). Not sure why setDelegate:nil and cancel didn't work, but replacing them with clearDelegatesAndCancel is fine (for other people, asihttprequest <=v1.7 don't support clearDelegatesAndCancel so you have to use setDelegate/cancel).